# TimeSpan.Parse Not Working When Processing CSV File

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, webforms

I am trying to upload tracks to my SQL database via a CSV file, but when I try to process the file, I get this exception:

```
System.FormatException
HResult=0x80131537
Message=String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan.
Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

Neither formatting time as `hh:mm:ss` or `h:mm:ss` works, though my CSV is very simple; a record looks like this:

```
TrackName,TrackLength,TrackNumber,AlbumID
Elected,00:04:05,3,6
```

My code is also very simple; it has worked for converting numbers and DateTimes. What am I doing wrong with the TimeSpans? I've been Googling a lot, but all I've found says `TimeSpan.Parse` is the best method for converting strings to timespans.

```
Dim csvData = From line As String In File.ReadAllLines(filenameWithPath)
    Skip 1
    Let CR = line.Split(",")
    Select New Track With {
        .TrackName = CR(0),
        .TrackLength = TimeSpan.Parse(CR(1)),
        .TrackNumber = CInt(CR(2)),
        .AlbumID = CInt(CR(3))
    }
```

**EDIT:** There is no reason for an exception to be thrown. Below is the full code for my button click event; there's only a simple If statement to check if the file upload control has a file. Nothing here should be causing problems.

```
    Private Sub BTN_Upload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN_Upload.Click
        If FU_CSV.HasFile Then
            Dim filenameWithPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Docs/Data/" & FU_CSV.FileName)
            FU_CSV.SaveAs(filenameWithPath)
            Dim csvData = From line As String In File.ReadAllLines(filenameWithPath)
            Skip 1
            Let CR = line.Split(",")
            Select New Track With {
                .TrackName = CR(0),
                .TrackLength = TimeSpan.Parse(CR(1)),
                .TrackNumber = CInt(CR(2)),
                .AlbumID = CInt(CR(3))
            }

            For Each t As Track In csvData
                context.Tracks.Add(t)
                context.SaveChanges()
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Did they develop it for VB.NET as well as C#?

Comment: OK. I'm looking for examples now. Having nested Using statements hasn't worked so far; `Using csv As New CsvHelper(reader)` is expecting a type.

Comment: If I only need to store hours, minutes, and seconds in my database, is it better to use DateTime or TimeSpan?

Comment: I just tried the exact data you specified and the exact code you specified and it worked perfectly.  DEBUG YOUR CODE!  Find out what the actual value of `CR(1)` is when the exception is thrown.  We shouldn't have to tell you this.

Comment: @Shortstuff81000 as  jmcilhinney said this code is working fine i also tried it. Do you have more records other than you have mentioned in your CSV file ? May be some of other record is causing a problem ?

Comment: Can you open your file in Excel and visually examine the data for any oddities. For example an empty value.

Comment: I wrote the file in Excel, but I figured it out, too; my simple code was looking for all commas and not ignoring those in quotes. Some of my track names had commas in them, so I deleted all of the commas from the album names and it worked! Dumb mistake. :D